# Set ActiveRecord Scopes In A Loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scopes

Why doesn't this work?

```
class Foo
  ...
  Status.each do |status|
    scope status, where(status: status)
  end
  ...
end
```

Now `Foo.new` it returns not an instance of Foo but an ActiveRecord::Relation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in ruby 1.9

```
Status.each do |status|
  scope status, -> { where(status: status) }
end
```

or in previous ruby versions

```
Status.each do |status|
  scope status, lambda { where(status: status) }
end
```

-- EDIT --

I guess your problem is somewhere else, since this code is working for me:

```
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :logo, :name
  validate :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  NAMES = %w(john matt david)
  NAMES.each do |name|
    scope name, -> { where(name: name) }
  end
end
```

I can create new models just fine and use the scopes

```
irb(main):003:0> Agency.new
=> #<Agency id: nil, name: nil, logo: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):004:0> Agency.matt
  Agency Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "agencies".* FROM "agencies" WHERE "agencies"."name" = 'matt'
=> []
irb(main):005:0> Agency.john
  Agency Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "agencies".* FROM "agencies" WHERE "agencies"."name" = 'john'
=> []
irb(main):006:0> Agency.david
  Agency Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "agencies".* FROM "agencies" WHERE "agencies"."name" = 'david'
=> []
```

Comment: I tried that. Same result. BTW, I should mention I'm on Ruby 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try to replicate and force me to look deeper. Huge duh. **One of the statuses is 'new'.** Yeah. BTW, using a lambda or not does not matter.